# Create serviceaccount for more then one namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create one serviceaccount in Kubernetes with the same token and give them access only to three namespaces. Is this possible in Kubernetes?

What I have done:

I create my serviceaccount:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount myuser
```

I Create a role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: myrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/attach
  - pods/exec
  - pods/portforward
  - pods/proxy
  - secrets
  - services/proxy
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

I create a ClusterRoleBinding

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
  name: myRoleBinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: myrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myuser
  namespace: wordpress
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myuser
  namespace: mysql
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myuser
  namespace: redis
```

I trying to get **secrets** in the namespace wordpress but get this:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User
"system:serviceaccount:default:myuser" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group
 "" in the namespace "wordpress"
```

Hope someone can help here.

Comment: You're using a service account in the `default` namespace, which isn't one of the ones you've assigned the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind that clusterrole to the service account in all three namespaces. To do this, create a namespaced rolebinding in each namespace.

i.e.

```
$ kubectl create rolebinding myrolebinding --serviceaccount=default:myuser --clusterrole=myrole --namespace=wordpress

$ kubectl create rolebinding myrolebinding --serviceaccount=default:myuser --clusterrole=myrole --namespace=namespace2

$ kubectl create rolebinding myrolebinding --serviceaccount=default:myuser --clusterrole=myrole --namespace=namespace3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

try putting this inside ur clusterrole

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: myrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "*"
  resources:
  - pods/attach
  - pods/exec
  - pods/portforward
  - pods/proxy
  - secrets
  - services/proxy
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```